# Python kivy app not working when converting to apk or exe

Tags: python, android, kivy, pyinstaller, kivymd

I recently made a PDF merger GUI with Kivy and KivyMD which works splendidly when running it through console doing "python3 main.py", but when converting it to either an APK through Buildozer or to an EXE using Pyinstaller it instantly crashes/closes on startup.

I am a real noob here so I honestly don't even know where to start to get to the problem, would really appreciate your help, thanks in advance! :)

```
from plyer import filechooser

import PyPDF2
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.button import MDRectangleFlatButton
from kivymd.uix.label import MDLabel
from kivymd.uix.screen import Screen
from kivymd.uix.textfield import MDTextFieldRound, MDTextField
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder

pdfSaveFileNameTextInput = """
MDTextField:
    hint_text: "Insert name of new PDF file"
    pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.35}
    size_hint_x: None
    width: 200

"""

class PDFMergeApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        application_window = Screen()
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Blue"
        self.theme_cls.primary_hue = "500"
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Light"

        label = MDLabel(text="Simple PDF Merger",
                        halign="center",
                        pos_hint={'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.7},
                        font_style="H3")
        application_window.add_widget(label)

        self.textInput = Builder.load_string(pdfSaveFileNameTextInput)
        application_window.add_widget(self.textInput)

        btn_flat = MDRectangleFlatButton(text="Merge PDFs",
                                         pos_hint={'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.2}
                                         )
        btn_flat.bind(on_release=self.pressed)
        application_window.add_widget(btn_flat)

        return application_window

    def pressed(self, instance):
        filename = filechooser.open_file(title="Choose pdfs to merge",
                                         multiple=True,
                                         filters=[("PDF Files (.pdf)", "*.pdf")])
        pdfOutputFileDirectory = filechooser.choose_dir()
        pdfOutputFileDirectory = ''.join(pdfOutputFileDirectory)

        pdfOutputFileName = self.textInput.text

        pdfOutputFile = open(pdfOutputFileDirectory + "\\" + pdfOutputFileName + ".pdf",
                             "wb")  # fd.asksaveasfile(mode='wb', defaultextension=".pdf")
        pdfWriter = PyPDF2.PdfFileWriter()

        for x in filename:
            pdfFiles = open(x, "rb")
            pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFiles)
            for pageNum in range(pdfReader.numPages):
                pageObj = pdfReader.getPage(pageNum)
                pdfWriter.addPage(pageObj)
                pdfWriter.write(pdfOutputFile)

        self.textInput.text = ""
        pdfOutputFile.close()


PDFMergeApp().run()
```

Comment: What error do you get when you run the exe from cmd?

Comment: I don't get an error when running it from cmd with "start main.exe". As far as I know, you can't debug external executables right?

The program just closes immediately.

Comment: if you run it from cmd (not by double click) and there is error like missing import (because some external package is not included in the bundle) you will see the full python traceback. Open cmd (Command Prompt), then from the shell/prompt run the exe. Running it from Start is same as double click.

Comment: Oh okay! Sorry I am very new to this.

Yes, I get:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'plyer'
[17780] Failed to execute script main

Is there some config file to edit so that I can include my missing imports?

Comment: try to specify plyer as `hidden import` check https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/when-things-go-wrong.html#listing-hidden-imports

Comment: As for Android - try to include it in `requirements` section in `buildozer.spec` file. Not sure if it will help, but likely it also cannot find it as requirement when building the apk.

Comment: Thanks, I'm closer to a solution, after recreating the exe with the hidden imports I know receive the following error, which I believe is due to my lack of knowledge of Kivy and more me writing bad code:

`[CRITICAL] [App         ] Unable to get a Window, abort.`

Is it because I don't have a init method?

Comment: Please, edit the question and add the full error, not just the last line. Also, I would suggest that you search/google the error - there are multiple question that refer to same error.

Comment: I feel like I am going away from my main question. You helped me fix that so thank you!

I'll research for a bit and update the question if I can't fix it myself, otherwise, I'll close it.

Once again, thank you very much!

Comment: just a suggestion, try to include also kivy as hidden import.

Comment: ***SOLUTION IS ON BELOW URL*** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70087326/kivy-app-not-working-while-running-on-samsung/70851456#70851456

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurs because you may not have specified the third party modules you used in the kivymd/kivy project file.

Open buildozer.spec file and in the requirements add **plyer ,PyPDF2**

After that completely delete the .buildozer directory or run **buildozer android clean** in the terminal.

Then Compile Again :)

Answer (score 0):

You should try to install `kivy 2.0.0rc4` in plugins trough settings. In which ever program you are using for coding. And your `buildozer.spec` should be like this:

```
# comma separated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
requirements = python3,kivy==2.0.0rc4,kivymd==0.104.2,plyer,pillow,sdl2_ttf==2.0.15,pypdf2
```