# I want to build the current code (smartphone camera streaming) for mobile using Buildozer

Tags: python, kivy, buildozer

I want to build the code below on Ubuntu as buildozer and run it on my phone. However, **buildozer-v android debug** works without any problems, so when installing it on a mobile phone, loading for a while...will be output and the application will exit. How do I set up buildozer.spec and build it so that I can run the code below after it's built on my smartphone?

If i add the code written below in buildzoer.spec, it still happens

Additionally, I want to run an app that streams on my smartphone without camera4kivy

```
requirements = kivy, opencv
android.permissions = CAMERA 
android.archs = arm64-v8a, armeabi-v7a
```

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.graphics.texture import Texture
import cv2

class CamApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.img1 = Image()
        layout = BoxLayout()
        layout.add_widget(self.img1)
        self.capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 1.0 / 33.0)
        return layout

    def update(self, dt):
        _, frame = self.capture.read()
        cv2.line(frame, (10,10),(50,50),(0,0,255),5)

        buf1 = cv2.flip(frame, 0)
        buf = buf1.tostring()
        texture1 = Texture.create(size=(frame.shape[1], frame.shape[0]), colorfmt='bgr')
        texture1.blit_buffer(buf, colorfmt='bgr', bufferfmt='ubyte')

        self.img1.texture = texture1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    CamApp().run()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: I would like to suggest that you review this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70087326/kivy-app-not-working-while-running-on-samsung/70851456#70851456). It may help you.